# Parameterized constructor Java

Tags: java, constructor

In Parameterized Constructor, Why we again need variable declaration.

Like the below code

`int id;` declared, then again in constructor `int i..id=I;`

```
class Student4{  
    int id;  
    String name;  

    Student4(int i,String n){  
        id = i;  
        name = n;  
    }    

    void display(){System.out.println(id+" "+name);}  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
    Student4 s1 = new Student4(111,"Karan");  
    Student4 s2 = new Student4(222,"Aryan");  
    s1.display();  
    s2.display();  
   }  
}
```

Comment: because not every parameter is exactly something that belongs to the Object you are creating,

Comment: The scope of method/constructor declaration parameters and (in this case) instance fields is different. They are not the same variables.

Comment: Declaration and assignment are separate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a "re-declaration" of variables, but an assignment instead, this is how parameters work.

I think you're confused because it's on the same class and it seems like you're never using the `id` variable but at the moment of creating a new student.

```
public Class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    Student() {
    }

    Student(int i, String n) {
        this.id = i;
        this.name = n;
    }

    //Add here getters & setters
}

public Class ClassRoom {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Student student1 = new Student(1, "John");
        Student student2 = new Student(2, "Sarah");

        System.out.println(student1.getId()); //This should print 1
        System.out.println(student2.getId()); //This should print 2

        //You may achieve the same result as follows:
        Student student3 = new Student();
        student3.setId(3);
        student3.setName("George");

        System.out.println(student3.getId()); //This should print 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you may have a case where you have multiple ways to insantiate the object based on what information you have.

For this class you could have several:

```
Student4(int i,String n){
  this.id = i;
  this.name = n;
}
Student4(int i) {
  this.id = i;
  this.name = "";
Student4(String n)
  this.name = n;
}
```

This is called overloading constructors.